# What does "commentator" command do in Counter-Strike 1.6

Tags: counter-strike

What is the "commentator" command in Counter-Strike 1.6, and how does it work?

Answer (score -1):

Apparently it works only on non steam servers. If you type

**commentator xc03335162**

You'll make the game think you are a HLTV viewer and not an actual player on the server. When you type status you won't be seeing your steamID but something HLTV related.

**Having a quick read, it seams this is used to unban yourself from said servers.**